# PHP Oracle function to return results from sql query

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I am looking run different sql queries through a function and return results... There will be many different queries going through this function.

I want the function to handle multiple different queries to parse, execute and fetch from the DB

```
$conn = oci_connect("{$username}", "{$password}", "{$db}");

if (!$conn) {

   $e=oci_error();
   trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);

} else {

   echo "Success";

}
```

Connection is made.

```
function oracle_test($stmt) {

  global $conn;
  global $sth;

  $sth = oci_parse($conn, $stmt);
  oci_execute($sth, OCI_DEFAULT);
  return $conn->oci_fetch_array($sth, OCI_ASSOC);

}


$sql = "select movie, title from schema.movies";
$mov2 = oracle_test($sql);

foreach ($mov2 as $row) {
      echo $row['MOVIE'] . $row['TITLE'];
}
```

What am I doing wrong here. No results are shown?

Comment: wrong database? wrong server, `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM schema.movies` also the word schema for your database seems also strange

Comment: db and server are fine - I can connect with no issues

Comment: issue is within the function or the foreach statement i believe

Comment: add an error handling, to see and var dump the variables. pice by piece, in other wirds standard debuging